# Tablesorter issue

Tags: javascript, html, tablesorter

I use tablesorter with javascript, which auto submits a form when the user clicks on a row in the table. All works well on the initial presentation of the table, until the user sorts the table into a new sequence using the column arrows. At that point, the javascript does not execute anymore, meaning it will not auto submit the form anymore until the user refreshes the page. I'm completely in the dark trying to get it to work.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.trclass').click(function()
{
  alert("test called");
  var serviceID = this.id;
  alert("serviceID :: " + serviceID);
  document.getElementById("xID").value = serviceID;
  document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit();
});
});
</script>
```

And the form it submits:

```
<form id="hiddenForm" method="post" action="xxxxxxxxxx.php">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="XXgeneratedToken"/>
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="XXuserid"/>
<input type="hidden" name="typeAction" value="edit"/>
<input id="xID" type="hidden" name="ID" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="phase" value="1"/>
</form>
```

And the table being sorted:

```
<tr height="10px" class="trclass" id="XXID">
<td style="width: 70px;">XXTitle</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXLast</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXFirst</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXPhone</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXEmailAddr</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXOptOut</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXAdmin</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXpg1</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXpg2</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXpg3</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXpg4</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXStatus</td>
<td style="width: 70px;">XXID</td>
</tr>
```

and the header:

```
<th style="width: 70px;">Title</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Last</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">First</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Phone</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Email</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">OptOut</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Admin</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Group 1</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Group 2</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Group 3</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Group 4</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">Status</th>
<th style="width: 70px;">ID</th>
```

Can someone help me with this issue? I'm pulling my hair out, and I don't have many left.
Thank you.

Comment: I think I asked a tough question, sorry. I did some major research, and found out how to upgrade to the latest version of Tablesorter. Lo, and behold, it is working great. Much better than before, and I even added the filter widget, which is great.

Thanks for your consideration.